# Is it possible to define rs.conf() in mongodb.conf?

Tags: mongodb

When you start mongod, you can pass in the location of a configuration file.

```
mongod --config /etc/mongodb-master.conf
```

Is it possible to define rs.conf() document in this file? I've looked at the docs and it states that you can define a replSet name in the config file, although setting this value didn't initialize the rs.conf() document when I started mongo.

Essentially I am wondering if you have to connect to a mongo instance every time when adding a new member to a replicate set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible. Besides specifying your Replicaset name in the conf file, the rest of the configuration is read from the `replset` collection in your  `local` database.

There's no way to override the contents of `local.replset` from the conf file. If it was possible, it would be too easy to reset the replica set configuration accidentaly.